# Armature Mesh is behaving weirdly

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I have been trying to rig my character in blender and did pretty good so far with it, but not sure what exactly is causing this. I am not very experienced, direction for what to do will be really great.

What I expect is the parts of the mesh to be in place no matter how the torso is being rotated, and any other body parts. Currently if I move any of the RightUpperArm for example, alot of the torso parts move as well for some reason.

https://gyazo.com/ab1952df6af6ba61fdfc4edbc71874a7

If you want to take a closer look at it - The blend file for it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUaaCNjCXuY4HcL-XfzYwUZVpYqVQJAi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0):

Your setting is a bit messy, some parentage *With Automatic Weights*, some *Child Of constraints*, etc...

For this kind of objects (robot, machine, manufactured object, etc) you have 2 solutions:

- Join all your objects into one, parent the object to the armature with the *With Empty Groups* mode, select the part you want in *Edit* mode, then in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups* choose the vertex group these vertices are supposed to be part of and click on the *Assign* button. The advantage of this solution is that you only have to deal with one object.
- Leave each part of your character separate, select the object you want, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, then *Set Parent to > Bone*, and so on for the other parts.

You can also use the *Child Of* constraint for each part, like you've done, but I'm not sure it as convenient, unless you have some reason to use this method? So maybe clean your settings and try one of the solutions I cite?